# Silent install of Vagrant to preferred directory on Windows

Tags: windows-installer, vagrant, silent-installer

**Description**

- [Download vagrant.msi](http://files.vagrantup.com/packages/db8e7a9c79b23264da129f55cf8569167fc22415/Vagrant_1.3.3.msi)
- Silent install vagrant to preferred directory by executing `msiexec /qn /i C:\temp\vagrant.msi INSTALLDIR=C:\preferredVagrantDirectory`

**Expected Result**

- Vagrant has been installed in `C:\preferredVagrantDirectory`

**Actual Result**

- Vagrant has been installed in `C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant`

Comment: You should contact the vendor for support.  Providing end user support for third party MSI's is outside of the scope of developer q&a.

Comment: Agreed. This question could be moved to SuperUser, but at least a reputation of 3K is required to perform this action.

Comment: @utrecht the question cannot be migrated due to the age.  Questions older than 60 days can't be migrated.  You will have to keep it here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pass `VAGRANTAPPDIR` instead of `INSTALLDIR`.

It's admirable that they created an MSI but they should know that the default installation should be [ProgramFilesFolder]Company\Product not [WindowsVolume]Company\Product. (Actually they do know since they did a cute little Type 51 SETPROPERTY WINDOWSVOLUME = [WindowsVolume] so they could author the directory table in a way to get past the built in ICE validation unit tests that warn developers to not do this very thing.  #FAIL

Also the use of unusual directory keys like VAGRANTAPPDIR only causes confusion.  Stick with INSTALLDIR, INSTALLLOCATION or TARGETDIR for InstallShield, VDPROJ and WiX projects respectively.

Comment: Thank you. I have changed INSTALLDIR to VAGRANTAPPDIR and vagrant is installed to the preferred location.

Comment: Agreed, but vote up requires 15 reputation and I only have 3. I have accepted the answer

Comment: Is there any way to get some sort of progress bar/updates on the command line?

Comment: You can do a /QR or /QB for a dialog that displays a progress bar but MSI doesn't support progress text at command line /stdout.  You'd have to write your own custom console app that called the MSI API to perform the install then surface the progress as ascii text or something.  I'm my 20+ years I've never seen anyone do this save one:  http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2010/09/worst-installer-ive-ever-seen.html?m=0